# In Python, how do I spawn in a new Python Process while the orginal is shutting down

Tags: python, background-process

I am making a python program (called A), where when the program recieves a Terminate Signal, it launches a different python program to run (called B). When A's program gets shutdown, the B program still needs to be still running in the background.

This is part of a cleanup function in a program I am writing for A. Also I don't have access to make any changes to B. (B is someone else's project, and not allowed to change it just build on top of it)

I been looking in using Popen or os.spawn function, when it receives the SIGTERM or SIGINT signals, but getting errors. 
When I tried os.spawn, it gave me an error saying that it could not find file name 'B.py programArgs', and it thought the progarmArgs was part of the filename.

Any ideas what I could do.

Code is something like this:

```
def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, onExit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, onExit)

def onExit(sig, frame):
    pid = os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, "usr/bin/python3", "python3", "/home/pi/filename", " programArg" )
```

Then it gives me the error:

```
Python3: can't open file '/home/pi/filename progarmArg': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you post what you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm not missing anything this should work

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python','B location'], stdout=None)
```

Comment: It worked, but I now getting that it ran the program in root and not as the pi user, as the python script is required to run in root. Going to see if I can fix that.

Comment: I don't understand. You just said it's running the program in root and that it is required to run in root. What's the problem?

Comment: This is a separate problem. The program needs to run in root as part of monitor as a network sniffer on it. That is why it is running root.